# Error on getting one part of a JSON response message to display in a textbox

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I'm working on parsing JSON data in a UWP app and this currently is my working code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        UsersObject MyGetRequest = await GetRequest();



        ResultTextBlock.Text = MyGetRequest.ToString() + " - ";

    }


  public static async Task<UsersObject> GetRequest()
    {
        Uri geturi = new Uri("url"); //replace your url
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(geturi);
        string response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //return response;

        var json = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersObject>(json);
        return result;
    }
```

And a UserObject class:

```
public class UsersObject { public List<UserObject> users = new List<UserObject>(); }
public class UserObject
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object userscol { get; set; }
    public string __href { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently getting an error on the line: UsersObject MyGetRequest = await GetRequest(); which says: "An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'HttpDemo.UsersObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

And the JSON i'm using is:

```
[
    {
        "username": "user1",
        "password": "10",
        "Id": 1,
        "userscol": null,
        "__href": "/db/GroupDBTest/users/Id/1.json"
    },
{
        "username": "user2",
        "password": "100",
        "Id": 2,
        "userscol": null,
        "__href": "/db/GroupDBTest/users/Id/2.json"
}
```

]

Comment: Can you please debug and paste the content of the "json" variable here?

Comment: @Declan The issue is with deserializing the response from the server. It's returning an array while you're expecting an object. Without an example response the best guess I can give is that you should be doing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserObject[]>(json);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your server returns a `List<UserObject>`. You are trying to convert that into a `UsersObject` which does only contain a `List<UserObject>` but is not a `List<UserObject>` itsself!

You need to do the following:

```
public static async Task<List<UserObject>> GetRequest()
{
    Uri geturi = new Uri("url"); //replace your url
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(geturi);
    string response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //return response;

    var json = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserObject>>(json);
    return result;
}


private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UsersObject myGetRequest = new UsersObject();
    myGetRequest.users = await GetRequest();

    //to iterate all users you got do this:
    foreach(var item in myGetRequest.users)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me 2 errors:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HttpDemo.UsersObject>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HttpDemo.UserObject>'

and:
 The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry for the first error. I will fix that in my example.
I didnt know if the app you were using was a Console-Application or not. Just delete the console.writline... it was just to show you how to iterate trough all users you got

Comment: OK @DeclanS. Just paste the whole thing again and look if it compiles :)

Comment: I got "An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Comment: And the json-string is still exactly the same? Are you sure you pasted the complete json? With everything that is in the variable?

Comment: Yeah thats all the JSON coming in through a web api from my database